# Error while trying to do load more than 200 users

Tags: jmeter

I am getting below given error while I try to do load test with more than 200 users.
My System config : 8GB RAM, 1 TB HDD, Core i5
Please help me to get solution for this error.

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
>   http://www.xxxxxx.ac.in refused
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The log says it all: The connection to your server timed out, i.e. it didn't respond in a reasonable amount of time which probably means that it gets too high of a load.

To fix this you need to fix up your server. But what exactly you need to fix there is impossible to determine here and would be way too long for SO.